# creating and access properties file in spring mvc

Tags: spring-mvc

[read this article on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10044789/accessing-application-properties-in-spring-mvc), and had some clarifying questions.

I put my config.properties under src/main/resources

In `spring-servlet.xml config file`

I added the following:

```
<context:property-placeholder location="classpath:config.properties"/>
```

In my business layer, I am trying to access it via

```
@Value("${upload.file.path}")
private String uploadFilePath;
```

Eclipse shows error:

```
The attribute value is undefined for the annotation type Value
```

Can i not access the property in the business layer or are property files only read in the controller?

UPDATE::
src/main/java/com.companyname.controllers/homecontroller.java

```
public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
    MyServiceObject myObj = new MyServiceObject();
    System.out.println("Property from my service object: = " + myObj.PropertyValue());

    if(myObj.PerformService())
    {
      ///
    }
}
```

src/main/java/com.companyname.services/MyService.java

```
public class MyServiceObject {

    @Value("${db.server.ip}")
    private String _dbServerIP;


    public String PropertyValue() {

        return _dbServerIPaseURL;
    }



}
```

[Another site where I found the explanation](http://www.finalconcept.com.au/article/view/spring-using-the-value-annotation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check that you import Value from org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation package:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
```

also the property placeholder must be declared in the respective context configuration file, in case of controller it's likely Spring dispatcher servlet configuration file.

**update** You are confusing [`property-placeholder`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-placeholderconfigurer) that post processes bean values, that contain dollar symbol `${<property name>}` with [Spring expression language container extension](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html#expressions-beandef) that process values containing a hash symbol `#{<Spring expression language expression>}`, in the link you have shown the latter approach is used.

**regarding the  instantiation of MyServiceObject myObj**
If you want the object to be managed by Spring you should delegate its creation to the container:

- if `MyServiceObject` is a stateless service then it's a singleton with the singleton bean scope, you should register it in your application context, for example with the following xml configuration:

  ```
  <bean class="my.package.MyServiceObject"/>
  ```

  and inject it to your controller:

  ```
  private MyServiceObject myServiceObject;
  @Autowired 
  public void setMyServiceObject(MyServiceObject myServiceObject){
     this.myServiceObject = myServiceObject;
  }
  ```
- if many instances of `MyServiceObject` are required, you can declare it as a bean with some other (non-singleton) bean scope (prototype, or request, for example). 
  However, as there's only one instance of the controller, you can't merely let the Spring container to autowire `MyServiceObject` instance to the controller field, because there will be only one field and many instances of `MyServiceObject` class. You can read about the different approaches(for the different bean scopes) for resolving this issue in [the respective section of the documentation](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/html/beans.html#beans-factory-scopes).

Comment: if it is not in the controller, where would the respective context config file be located?

Comment: Did changing  imports in the controller java file solved the problem? In spring MVC you typically have IoC containers and at least two configuration files http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11708967/what-is-the-difference-between-applicationcontext-and-webapplicationcontext-in-s/11709272#11709272

Comment: If it's a dao or a service(not controller) than the it will be the root web app context configuration file I believe. Assuming that the DAOs are instantiated in the root web app context, of course.

Comment: theory http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11890544/spring-value-annotation-in-controller-class-not-evaluating-to-value-inside-pro

Comment: Adding the import did not solve the problem. The compile error went away, however it does not seem to read from the property file.

Comment: @user1361914 can you give more information about the business object? how is it instantiated - the class source and the bean declaration

Comment: Boris Treukhov: Thanks for the answer. Just getting hands dirty on spring and playing with a test project that I have converting from .net to spring mvc

Comment: @user1361914 Then pls accept this as the answer, or the question will remain in the SO list of unanswered ones. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/19787/discussion-between-user1361914-and-boris-treukhov)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method that allows us to fetch whatever values are needed from a property file.  This can be in Java code (Controller class) or in a JSP.

- Create a property file WEB-INF/classes/**messageSource.properties** It will be in the classpath and accessible in both controllers and JSTL.
  Like any property file, this one consists of a key and a value

  For example:
  hello=Hello JSTL, Hello Contoller

**For the Controllers**

- Locate the xml file that you use to define your Spring beans.  In my case it is named servlet-context.xml.  You may need to determine that by looking in your web.xml in cases where you are using the servlet contextConfigLocation property.
- Add a new Spring bean definition with the id="messageSource". This bean will be loaded at runtime by Spring with the property file key value pairs. Create the bean with the following properties:

  - bean id="messageSource"
  - class = org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource
  - property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/classes/messageSource
- In the bean definition file for the controller class (testController) add the messageSource as a property.  This will inject the messageSource bean into the controller.

  - bean id="testController" class="com.app.springhr.TestController"
  - beans:**property name="messageSource" ref="messageSource**"
- In the controller JAVA class, add the messageSource Spring Bean field and its getters and setters. Note the field type is ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.

  private org.springframework.context.support.**ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource** messageSource;

  public org.springframework.context.support.**ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource** getMessageSource() {
          return messageSource;
      }

  public void setMessageSource(
              org.springframework.context.support.**ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource** messageSource) {
          this.messageSource = messageSource;
      }
- In your controller code, you can now fetch any known property value from the bundle.

  String propValue = getMessageSource().getMessage("hello", objArray, null);

**Using JSTL**

Since the property file messageSource.properties is in the classpath, JSTL will be able to find it and fetch the value for the given key.

- Add the import of the fmt taglib

  - taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" prefix="fmt"
  - Use the fmt:tag in the JSP to fetch a value from the property file.

    Sorry about the pseudo syntax, this editor doesn't seem to render any XML.

    fmt:bundle basename="messageSource"

    fmt:message key="hello"
  - Hope this helps others